# Составить Программу на языке С++ для циклического нахождение значения арифметического высказывание

Tags: c++, циклы

[image: Собственно само задание]

> Зачет прошел, задание завалено, но все равно нужна помощь с решением, что-бы знать на будущее(С++ я вообще не знаю)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Вынесем x за знак суммы, и останется найти сумму `1/i^2`. Да, у вас как-то странно у суммы стоят индексы. Будет просто считать их опечаткой, и что `i=1` внизу, а 10 вверху.

```
double S(double x)
{ 
    double s = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
        s += 1./i/i;
    return x*s;
}
```

Вот и всё.